# Styling google forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, google-forms

I'm trying to customize the layout of a google form by creating my own html and using the entry.xxxxxxxxx names. It's a multisection Google Form, which makes it's harder to manage, I think.

I've used the Google Forms HTML Exporter from Stefano Brilli, but I didn't manage to get the pagehistory to work.

So I bought the Just Forms Pro Advanced by lazycode to adjust this form.
But the form somehow uses the input name, which in this case, I have to change to entry.xxxxxxxxx. And this name contains a point, which apparently is not supported in jquery? Does anyone have a solution for this? Is there a way I can use, for example, the id instead of the name?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact form</title>

    <!-- Your META here -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="j-pro/css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="j-pro/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="j-pro/css/j-pro-modern.css">

    <script src="j-pro/js/jquery.2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="j-pro/js/jquery.j-pro.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="bg-pic">

    <div class="j-wrapper j-wrapper-640">
        <form action="j-pro/php/action.php" method="post" class="j-pro j-multistep" id="contact" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

            <div class="j-header">
                <p>Contact Us</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end /.j-header-->

            <div class="j-content">

                <!-- start steps -->
                <div class="j-row j-step-titles">
                    <div class="j-span6 j-step-title">
                        <div class="j-steps">
                            <span>Step 1:</span>
                            <p>Personal info</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="j-span6 j-step-title">
                        <div class="j-steps">
                            <span>Step 2:</span>
                            <p>Message</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end steps -->

                <fieldset>

                    <!-- start First name Last name-->
                    <div class="j-row">
                        <div class="j-span6 j-unit">
                            <label class="j-label">First name</label>
                            <div class="j-input">
                                <label class="j-icon-right" for="first_name">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" name="entry.671783982" id="first_name" class="name-group">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="j-span6 j-unit">
                            <label class="j-label">Last name</label>
                            <div class="j-input">
                                <label class="j-icon-right" for="last_name">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="name-group">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end First name Last name -->

                    <!-- start email -->
                    <div class="j-unit">
                        <label class="j-label">Your email</label>
                        <div class="j-input">
                            <label class="j-icon-right" for="email">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end email -->

                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>

                    <!-- start subject -->
                    <div class="j-unit">
                        <label class="j-label">Your subject</label>
                        <div class="j-input">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end subject -->

                    <!-- start message -->
                    <div class="j-unit">
                        <label class="j-label">Your message</label>
                        <div class="j-input">
                            <textarea spellcheck="false" name="message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end message -->

                </fieldset>

                <!-- start response from server -->
                <div class="j-response"></div>
                <!-- end response from server -->

            </div>
            <!-- end /.content -->

            <div class="j-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="j-primary-btn">Send</button>
                <button type="button" class="j-primary-btn j-multi-next-btn">Next</button>
                <button type="button" class="j-secondary-btn j-multi-prev-btn">Back</button>
            </div>
            <!-- end /.footer -->

        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready( function(){
            $( "#contact" ).justFormsPro({
                rules:{
                    entry.671783982: {
                        requiredFromGroup: [1, ".name-group"]
                    },
                    last_name: {
                        requiredFromGroup: [1, ".name-group"]
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    subject: {
                        required: false
                    },
                    message: {
                        required: true
                    },
                },
                messages:{
                    entry.671783982: {
                        requiredFromGroup: "First name or last name is required"
                    },
                    last_name: {
                        requiredFromGroup: "First name or last name is required"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Email is required",
                        email: "Incorrect email format"
                    },
                    subject: {
                        required: "Subject is required"
                    },
                    message: {
                        required: "Message is required"
                    }
                },
                formType: {
                    multistep: true
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried multiple other ways but I'm totally stuck at this moment. I can make it work if people always fill in all the fields of the form. So it doesn't need to be checked if everything is filled in correctly. But if they don't, the form redirects to the google form itself to complete it, so that looks kinda silly.
That's why I purchased this form, but now I'm stuck because of the entry.xxxxxxxxx.

I do need Google Forms since it's also working together with Document Studio, which triggers an action when a Google Form is submitted.